# Do Professional Manufacturers Violate IPC Standards?

Tags: pcb, surface-mount, layout, manufacturing, ipc

I lay out simple boards using BGA packages and often ignore my EDA tool's courtyards. I know these courtyards are set by IPC standards to allow for good design, but then I look at boards like the iPhone X's motherboard and think, darn, Apple's cheating! Their courtyards are non-existent and they have decoupling capacitors side by side with their silicon!
[image: iPhone X Motherboard]

So basically, why can they "break the rules" while I need to keep my components spaced apart?

Comment: Well, they aren't rules or laws, just standards that people abide by (or not) to make communications easier about what kind of capabilities you can expect. Often I have to break IPC "recomendations", its just a matter of asking your fab house if its possible. Answers will vary from "sure no problem", to "no" or, "we can try, but then we have no responsibility over the assembled board", or "ok but yield might be low", and so on. TLDR: there is no IPC police :)

Comment: Then why do they charge people $5000 for a PDF of their "standards"? :)

Comment: @Sam maybe it's cheaper than trial and error

Comment: It’s in a dust-proof phone and Foxconn can place them as close as the designer chooses

Comment: Apple may have a different assembly process than what you're targeting. BGA packages have the contacts underneath, they can't accommodate a soldering iron, so a courtyard only serves for pick-and-place positioning tolerance. The placement of the capacitors definitely looks like pick-and-place with reflow, it's too tight for hand assembly. That's not "cheating", it's manufacturing. The IPC standards are a good place to start, but they're not a matter of law.

Comment: By the way, that image apparently comes from [ifixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Image/meta/lvNMg3CTpGTnenf6), CC BY-NC-SA, you may have forotton to give attirbution...

Comment: The standards are (supposed to be) also a good compromise between pushing the tech and manufacturability, which involves a lot of trial and error. Instead of having to try for yourself and fix a bunch of pcbs and redo batches, you buy a recommended standard from someone who did a lot of testing.

Answer (score 2):

IPC rules don't really depend on the PCB manufacturing process. They're mainly about the PCB **assembly** process.

The recommended pad sizes ensure there's enough solder paste to hold the component in place. The toe-room ensures a good solder fillet can be formed. Overall they provide very generous allowance for placement tolerance.

The courtyard mainly makes the order of pick and place operations not matter (you don't have to worry about programming the small parts to be placed before the tall parts), and ensures enough room to fit a hot-air nozzle around the part in case re-work is required.

If you don't need to do re-work (either your part is cheap enough to scrap in case of defects, or your customer is willing to pay a premium for a compact product) then you reduce your courtyards dramatically compared to IPC recommendations.

On the other hand if you follow IPC recommendations you can choose from a wide selection of assembly houses, including ones using quite dated pick and place machines, and expect to get high yields (and thus low overall costs).